# Transpose table with a twist: aggregate similar field on the same row

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been searching all morning for an answer to the following question (please excuse me if this is a repost but I am really getting crazy with this issue).

I have the following table of relations `R1, R2, R3, R4, R5` between clients `AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD` and persons `XXX,YYY,ZZZ`

```
relation_id   client  in_relation_with  relation_type
---           ---     ---               ---
1             AAA     XXX               R1
2             AAA     YYY               R1
3             AAA     ZZZ               R3
4             BBB     XXX               R2
5             BBB     YYY               R5
6             CCC     XXX               R2
7             DDD     ZZZ               R4
8             DDD     YYY               R4
9             DDD     XXX               R4
```

And I would like to have the following table:

```
client  R1.1      R1.2      R2       R3       R4.1     R4.2    R4.3    R5
---     ---       ---       ---      ---      ---      ---     ---     ---
AAA     XXX       YYY       -        ZZZ      -        -       -       -
BBB     -         -         XXX      -        -        -       -       YYY
CCC     -         -         XXX      -        -        -       -       -
DDD     -         -         -        -        XXX      YYY     ZZZ     -
```

The problem is that a client (`DDD`) can have similar relations (type `R4`) with different persons (`XXX, YYY, ZZZ`) and that the number of persons with whom our client is in relation with is a priori unknown but can be found with a `max` statement on the `relations` table.
The hard part are coming up with these `R1.1, R1.2, R4.1...` columns and the `null` where no relation exist (at least to me)...

Is it at all possible to that in PL/SQL?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

G

Comment: may have found something at:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3689491/Oracle-Database-Rotating-Tables.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code. See also [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78736/8/0) for the fiddle

```
select 
  client,
  case when instr(r1, ',')>=1 then regexp_substr(r1,'[^,]+',1,1) else r1   end r1_1,
  case when instr(r1, ',')>=1 then regexp_substr(r1,'[^,]+',1,2) else null end r1_2,
  r2,
  r3,
  case when instr(r4, ',')>=1 then regexp_substr(r4,'[^,]+',1,1) else r1   end r1_1,
  case when instr(r4, ',')>=1 then regexp_substr(r4,'[^,]+',1,2) else null end r4_2,
  case when instr(r4, ',')>=1 then regexp_substr(r4,'[^,]+',1,3) else null end r4_3,
  r5
  from( 
    with relations as (
      select 1 relation_id, 'AAA' client, 'XXX' in_relation_with, 'R1' relation_type from dual union all
      select 2            , 'AAA'       , 'YYY'                 , 'R1'               from dual union all
      select 3            , 'AAA'       , 'ZZZ'                 , 'R3'               from dual union all
      select 4            , 'BBB'       , 'XXX'                 , 'R2'               from dual union all
      select 5            , 'BBB'       , 'YYY'                 , 'R5'               from dual union all
      select 6            , 'CCC'       , 'XXX'                 , 'R2'               from dual union all
      select 7            , 'DDD'       , 'ZZZ'                 , 'R4'               from dual union all
      select 8            , 'DDD'       , 'YYY'                 , 'R4'               from dual union all
      select 9            , 'DDD'       , 'XXX'                 , 'R4'               from dual
    )
      select *       
        from relations
        pivot(
          listagg(in_relation_with, ',') 
          within group(order by relation_id)
          for relation_type in ('R1' as r1, 'R2' as r2, 'R3' as r3, 'R4' as r4, 'R5' as r5)
        )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think something like the bellow solution, which can be changed to parsing the delimeter separated values to transform them to columns.

```
with relations as (select 1 relation_id, 'AAA' client, 'XXX' in_relation_with, 'R1' relation_type
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 2, 'AAA', 'YYY', 'R1'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 3, 'AAA', 'ZZZ', 'R3'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 4, 'BBB', 'XXX', 'R2'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 5, 'BBB', 'YYY', 'R5'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 6, 'CCC', 'XXX', 'R2'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 7, 'DDD', 'ZZZ', 'R4'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 8, 'DDD', 'YYY', 'R4'
                      from dual
                    union all
                    select 9, 'DDD', 'XXX', 'R4'
                      from dual
                    )
select *       
  from relations
pivot
(
listagg(in_relation_with, ',') within group(order by relation_id)
for relation_type in ('R1' as r1, 'R2' as r2, 'R3' as r3, 'R4' as r4, 'R5' as r5)
)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, indeed it helps although as you mention the issue is then to transform these pseudo columns into real columns.. but at least for now it's good :)

Comment: in combo with what can be find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659705/split-a-column-into-multiple-columns-by-a-delimiter-that-may-or-may-not-be-ther
\o/